# Automatically create object

Tags: python, django

Django beginner here.

```
class A(models.Model):
    b = models.ForeignKey(B)
    ...

class B(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    ...
```

I want to be able to create an instance of `A` without explicitly specifying an instance of `B`. I found that the `ForeignKey` field accepts a `default` parameter, but I haven't been able to figure out how to make it create one instance per user.

Something like

```
class A(models.Model):
    b = models.ForeignKey(B, default=B(user=request.user))
```

but that obviously won't work, because the model doesn't know about `request`.

What is a good way to create this default instance, at the time it is needed (when `A` is created, not when `User` is created)? Where the proper place for it?

Answer (score 0):

> What is a good way to create this default instance, at the time it is needed (when A is created)

Clearly.  That's the only thing that can work.

There are various kinds of defaults.  Model defaults exist outside any application.

This is a good example of something that can't be a "model" default because it depends on the current session and the current User associated with that session.

It's an "application" default.  It goes **outside** the model.  Ideally, it's simply part of a View function.

If you want to use the default admin, then you do this by extending the Admin class definitions to include this default value.

Comment: Didn't understand a word. Are you saying it is not possible, and I should instead do an explicit check in each place that wants to create `A`?

Comment: "at the time it is needed" seemed pretty clear.  And they were your words.  I guess that didn't help.  t tried to emphasize this with "It goes outside the model".  I guess that didn't help, either.  Since "didn't understand a word" is a very sweeping and vague statement, it would help if you could focus a bit.  Otherwise, I can't really figure out how to rewrite it.

Comment: I guess your answer makes sense to someone already familiar with the things you're suggesting, but that's unfortunately not me. I have no clue what to do after reading it.

Comment: "at the time it is needed" seemed pretty clear. And they were your words. Let's try to focus on those six words.  How are your words confusing you?  Can you be **specific**?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
class A(models.Model):
    b = models.ForeignKey(B)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = kwargs["user"]
        if not self.id and not self.b:
            obj_b = B.objects.create(user=user)
        self.b = obj_b
        return super(A, self).save(*args, **kwargs)   

class B(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

But this is a very special unflexible solution.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to be able to create an instance of A without explicitly
>   specifying an instance of B.

```
class A(models.Model):
    b = models.ForeignKey(B,blank=True,null=True)
```